# If $f$ is entire and $f(z)\to \infty$, for $z\to \infty$ , then $f(z)$ is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

> If $f$ is entire and $f(z)\to \infty,$ for $z\to \infty$ , then $f(z)$ is polynomial.

As $f(z)\to \infty, for z\to \infty$ then $\exists M,$ such that $|z|>M$ implies $|f(z)|>1$ 
COnsider COmpact set $\overline {B(0,M)}$ Then  $f(z)$ has finite zeros in that compact set say $x_1,...,x_n$ 
Now $\frac{f(z)}{(z-x_1)...(z-x_n)}=g(z)$ is never vanishing function and tend to infinity.
ALso  $h(z)=1/g(z)$ is holomorphic .
Now I can not abel to proceed further 
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: what's forz --> ∞

Comment: Maybe OP Says f(z) tends to infntity as z tend a to infinity

Answer (score 4):

For $z \ne 0$ let $g(z):=f(1/z)$. Then $g$ hat an isolated singularity at $z=0$. From $g(z) \to \infty$ for $z \to 0$ we see that $g$ has a pole ate $z=0$.

Let $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$, then $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{z^n}$.

Since $g$ has a
pole at $z=0$, there is $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_m=0$ for $m>n$.

Comment: This is not rigorously correct but the ideas are shown intuitively. Writing g(z) in such a form presupposes the analyticity of g at infinity, which is obviously not the case if there is a pole at infinity.