# Prove that a function that is analytic everywhere except a finite number of poles is rational

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, singularity

Let $f$ be an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}  \cup \{\infty\}$ except a finite number of poles. I need to prove that $f$ is rational.

Let the poles be $a_1,...,a_k$, So I know that $f$ can be written as $\frac{g(z)}{(z-a_1)^{m_1} \cdots (z-a_k)^{m_k}}$ whrere $g$ is entire and $g(a_i) \neq 0$ for every $i$.

Since $g$ is analytic, I can write it as a power series. However, here I got stuck since I don't see how to show that this power series has only finite amount of powers.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you only know that $h \to \infty $ at $a$ then you need to show $(z-a)^2/h(z)$  is holomorphic thus analytic at $a$ thus $h$ has a pole. In the case $a=\infty $ look at $z^2/h(1/z)$. At the end you obtain an entire function with polynomial growth at $\infty$ to which you can apply Liouville.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g$ has a pole at $\infty$ then $|g(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$ and it is well known that $g$ is  a polynomial in this case. [See [If $f$ is entire and $f(z)\to \infty$, for $z\to \infty$ , then $f(z)$ is polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924936/if-f-is-entire-and-fz-to-infty-for-z-to-infty-then-fz-is-polyno) ] Otherwise $g$ is entire and it is also analytic at $\infty$ which makes it bounded. By Louivile's Theorem $g$ is a constant so $f$ is a rational function.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about using Louivile's theroem

Comment: So it is the same when, there is only one simple pole? still a rational function, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.